# vue-test-utils conflict between suits

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

I have two test suits, if I run them independently all tests pass : 
[image]

But if I run them together, there seems to be a problem with my wrapper

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined:
>   [image]

Here's my what both of my "beforeEach" looks like

TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

```
describe('Modal.vue', () => {
  let store: any;
  let wrapper: any;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    store = new Vuex.Store(cloneDeep(StoreConfig));
    wrapper = shallowMount(Modal, {
      localVue,
      store,
    });
  });
  // Tests...
});

describe('Navigation.vue', () => {

  let store: any;
  let wrapper: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const router = new VueRouter();
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(VueRouter);
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    store = new Vuex.Store(cloneDeep(StoreConfig));
    wrapper = shallowMount(Navigation, {
      localVue,
      router,
      store,
      propsData: {
        user: {},
      },
    });
  }); 

  it('show a login button when user is a guest', () => {
    setUserAsGuest();

    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('Login');
  });

  const setUserAsGuest = () => {
    wrapper.setProps({
      user: {
        role: 'guest',
      },
   });
  // More Tests...
});
```

I have tried everything that I could think of, so I am now turning myself to you guys!

Comment: Could you, please, provide relevant part of test code that fails to access `props`?

Comment: @aBiscuit I updated the code for Navigation.vue with the test that fails

Comment: Which version of `vue` and `vue-test-utils` do you use in this project?

Comment: Vue is 2.5.17, vue-test-utils is 1.0.0-beta.20. The project was installed using vue-cli 3 so I didn't install them manually.